# Hook construction of objects

Tags: javascript, constructor, proxy, wrapper, interceptor

I am trying to intercept the construction of all objects.

```
function inheritFrom(){
 this.property = 'Example'
}

let inheritedObject = new inheritFrom()
```

Whenever an object instantiation happens, I want to intercept it and `` console.log(`${object} was constructed as example..`) ``

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no way to do this for *every* construction, but it's trivial to wrap any given constructor in a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and trap the [call to construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/construct). Note that this does not *modify* the proxied class/constructor function, callers will have to construct your proxy for the trap to fire. Also note that proxies can have negative impacts on performance, be sure to profile.

Comment: Right.  There is no way to inject this surreptitiously.  You need the cooperation of the program.

Comment: @JaredSmith You don't need a proxy to wrap a constructor function

Comment: @Bergi that's true enough. Proxy does have that trap though. IDK the whole idea is maybe a little off, unless OP clarifies more the *why* of what they hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ES6 classes you could inherit every class from some base class and do logging in it:

```js
class Base{
  constructor(){
    console.log(new.target.name, 'created');
  }
}


class inheritFrom extends Base{
 property = 'Example'
}

let inhertedObject = new inheritFrom()
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not making use of [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)? ... thus logging ... `console.log(new.target.name, 'created');` ... instead of ... `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.name, 'created');`

Comment: @PeterSeliger haven't used `new.target.name` before, thanks for the tip, updated the answer